# Making recyclerview not jump to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am executing `getMessages()` every minute and it jumps everytime to the top because of the

`myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

How can I make so that the Recyclerview holds it's position even if it's updated or not?

```
    private void getMessages() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, response -> {
            try{
                if (lstMessages != null) {
                    lstMessages.clear();
                }
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            chatModel um = new chatModel();
                            um.setM_msg(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                            lstMessages.add(um);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }catch (JSONException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!started) {
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                rv_msg.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                chat myadapter = new chat(this, lstMessages);
                rv_msg.setAdapter(myadapter);
                start();
            } else {
               chat myadapter = new chat(this, lstMessages);
                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, error -> {
            MySingleton.getmInstance(this).MySingletonClear(this);
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("aa", String.valueOf(aa));
                param.put("bb", String.valueOf(bb));

                return param;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: Check [Diff Util](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this code

```
View v = rv_msg.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ?0 : v.getTop();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(lstMessages.size(), top);
```

after `myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

If you clear list of data and use `notifyDataSetChanges()` recyclerview will refresh all items.

You can use distinct function to prevent duplicate data.
Here is an example distinct function:

```
private void distinctMessages(List<Message> newMessages) {
    if (lstMessages.size() < 1 || lstMessages == null) {
        lstMessages.addAll(newMessages);

        return;
    }

    for (Message newMessage: newMessages) {
        boolean hasSameMessages = false;
        
        for (Message currentMessage: lstMessages) {
            if (newMessage.getId().equals(currentMessage.getId())) {
                hasSameMessages = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasSameMessages) {
            lstMessages.add(newMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it in your existing code like this :

```
private void getMessages() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, response -> {
        try{
            ArrayList<Message> newMessages = new ArrayList<Message>;
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    chatModel um = new chatModel();
                    um.setM_msg(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                    newMessages.add(um);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            distinctMessages(newMessages);
        }catch (JSONException e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!started) {
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            rv_msg.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            chat myadapter = new chat(this, lstMessages);
            rv_msg.setAdapter(myadapter);
            start();
        } else {
            chat myadapter = new chat(this, lstMessages);
            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, error -> {
        MySingleton.getmInstance(this).MySingletonClear(this);
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("aa", String.valueOf(aa));
            param.put("bb", String.valueOf(bb));

            return param;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Please take a look [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged())

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)` ? You have to use this instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()` while appending new items.

Add a method inside your adapter like below:

```
 public void appendListToAdapter(List<String> list) {
    int currentListSize = this.mList.size();
    this.mList.addAll(list);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(currentListSize, list.size());
}
```

Just grab the old list size into `currentListSize` and pass it to method.

Now call this method when you need to append your list with new messages.